# How to use foreach

Tags: php

this array is a product of a process which i push to this array and when i use nested foreach and echo it gives me all the values from it.

```
foreach ($arr as $key) {
        foreach ($key as $keys => $values) {
            echo $values;
        }
```

My question is how can assign it in variable so that I can distinguish where it belongs

```
Array
(
    [logs] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2014-09-22 01:24:56
            [1] => 2014-09-22 10:53:35
            [2] => 2014-09-22 07:49:45
            [3] => 2014-09-22 06:49:29
        )

    [fullname] => Array
        (
            [0] => DORIS JOHNSON
            [1] => JOHN DOE
            [2] => JOHN DOE
            [3] => JOHN DOE
        )

    [id] => Array
        (
            [0] => 785739
            [1] => 404150
            [2] => 404150
            [3] => 404150
        )

    [misc] => Array
        (
            [0] => Etc
            [1] => Other
            [2] => Etc
            [3] => Etc
        )

    [status] => Array
        (
            [0] => MARRIED
            [1] => SINGLE
            [2] => SINGLE
            [3] => SINGLE
        )

)
```

I need to make and use the keys as a variable 
like if i need to output it.

```
echo $logs;
echo $fullname;
echo $id;
echo $misc;
echo $status;
```

expected output:

```
2014-09-22 01:24:56 | DORIS JOHNSON | 785739 | Etc | MARRIED

2014-09-22 10:53:35 | JOHN DOE | 404150 | Other | SINGLE

and soon...
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How 'foreach' actually works](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10057671/how-foreach-actually-works) and [How can use foreach to Loop Through PHP Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3027719/how-can-use-foreach-to-loop-through-php-array).

Comment: Your array structure is a little odd. Shouldn't you be holding the different elements for each record in one array, with each array containing a new record? It'll be a whole lot easier to work with.

Answer (score 1):

Simple and nice way to 'rotate' array, without foreach loops

```
array_unshift($arr, null);
$arr = call_user_func_array('array_map', $arr);
```

And than just output it anyway you want.

```
foreach($arr as $s)
    echo join(' | ', $s) . '<br>';
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like

```
foreach ($arr['logs'] as $key => $val) {        
    //make a new index and put related elements into it
    $arr['result'][$key] = array();
    array_push($arr['result'][$key], $arr['logs'][$key], $arr['fullname'][$key], $arr['id'][$key], $arr['misc'][$key]);
}

foreach($arr['result'] as $val) {
    //loop through the new index and echo the result in provided format
    echo implode(" | ",$val)."<br/>";
}
```